3D graphs arrow heads
i have made the 3D graph, and the only thing im missing is the arrow heads on the z, y and x axis. But i dont know how.

This pucture shows my work so far, but i really dont understand how i can make the arrow heads. This picture is what i'm going for:

Look closely at especially how the arrow heads lays on the xy-level. They look like they lay in 2d which is what i really dont know how to do.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Try to add -> as option to your lines.

If you want them to be oriented like that, you may need to draw them in a plane with \pgflowlevelsynccm

welcome! please, never post images of code (or errors etc.). images can't be copy-pasted to reproduce your issue, can't be indexed to help future readers find solutions and are meaningless to readers who depend on screen-reading software. instead, paste your code as text into your question, highlight it and use the {} button to format as code. you can use the edit link at the bottom left of your post.
